# How to use pyang module to compile, validate yang operations and sending back command to device

Tags: import, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

I am working on a project where i have to get yang files from device , edit them and then validate the yang structure and send back command as RPC to the device.

I am able to login into device using ncclient on port 830

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to read & validate simple xml or json  file as yang file